# Capture output from very long running python subprocess event driven

Tags: python, subprocess, buffer, python-multithreading, io-redirection

The problem I am facing is that I have a subprocess in python (ffmpeg process) that runs for hours or even days from which I'd like to capture the output. The subprocess its stdout/err.PIPE can easily grow huge and needs to be flushed otherwise the program will grow out of memory (limit of PIPE size). I do not like to constantly parse the output but ondemand (event driven) and very important, get the latest output from the sub-process.

My current approach is to send the output to a LifoQueue with size 0 so I only keep the last result for when I need to process it.

I an other attempt I've tried to assign stdout to /dev/null and when needed re-assign it when I'd like to read the output but failed miserably thus far.

As a proof of concept I have made these programs but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient/pythonic way of handling this issue, also I'd like to avoid using threads.

This is the best solution I could come-up with for now.

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading
import Queue


class FlushPipe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.command = ['python', './print_date.py']
        self.process = None
        self.process_output = Queue.LifoQueue(0)
        self.capture_output = threading.Thread(target=self.output_reader)

    def output_reader(self):
        for line in iter(self.process.stdout.readline, b''):
            self.process_output.put_nowait(line)

    def start_process(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.command,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.capture_output.start()

    def get_output_for_processing(self):
        return self.process_output.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flush_pipe = FlushPipe()
    flush_pipe.start_process()

    now = time.time()
    while time.time() - now < 10:
        print ">>>" + flush_pipe.get_output_for_processing()
        time.sleep(2.5)

    flush_pipe.capture_output.join(timeout=0.001)
    flush_pipe.process.kill()
```

print_date.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print str(time.time())
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

output:

```
>>>1520535158.51
>>>1520535161.01
>>>1520535163.51
>>>1520535166.01
```

Comment: what about just reading line by line? `for line in self.process.stdout:`

Comment: this is not addressing the fact that the PIPE will grow out of memory! Futher more, there is no last line since output will be generated constantly and it will thus block the futher execution of my program.

Comment: well, you're already reading line by line...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. That is true, but that is in another (non-blocking) thread, hence the main program is not blocked. Also I got the latest output when I need it, I don't have to read through the whole 'history'. But what I would like to see is a solution without threads or (most preferred) where I can assign the stdout=subprocess.PIPE on demand and when not needed I assign it to /dev/null.